# Insert a table inside iFrame in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, iframe

I have created a table in jsp. I want to insert it inside a frame. I used the below code to do it but it is showing only a white background. My table is not visible.

```
        <IFRAME frameborder="0"  
          style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: margin: 0px;"  
          id="filterIFrame" name="filterIFrame" scrolling="yes"  
          src="serverpanel.jsp">
```

Comment: Are you getting request on server for `serverpanel.jsp`? If so, does that page work outside `iframe` to produce the table?

Comment: If i remove the iFrame code, I am able to view my table. I inserted the above code, to fit my table inside a frame. But it is not transparent.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  I had the color code backwards as it made the text be in white type which blended in with the white window.  check this out as it doesn't hurt.